# Xamarin Firebase iOS Analytics throwing AOT MTOUCH ERROR MT3001 - Firebase.Analytics.dll

Tags: firebase, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, firebase-analytics, .net-standard-2.0

I'm trying to integrate Firebase Analytics to my xamarin forms application. For Xamarin.IOS I'm using **Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Analytics** version 5.0.1

And getting the below error while building.

./iOS/MTOUCH: Error MT3001: Could not AOT the assembly '/iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/Build/Firebase.Analytics.dll' (MT3001)

Not able to understand what could go wrong. Is there any configuration changed I have to do.?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly ,make sure that your VS and Xcode are up-to-date. If the issue continue, you can right

> click your project ->options->iOS build ->Linker Behavior

set the value as Don’t Link. In addition, delete the folder obj and bin and rebuild your project again.